# Analyticity of a function.

Tags: complex-analysis

Does Cauchy-Riemann Equation always guarantee the analyticity of a function.

Consider $\frac 1 z$. When we apply $z=x+iy$ and find the $u_x,u_y,v_x,v_y$, we know it will satisfies the C-R Equation. But, since it has singularity then it's not analytic at $z=0$

How do we know the function is analytic or holomorphic? (Suppose, I wouldn't consider their expression on Taylor series). Is it enough that  if the function has a singularity, it's not analytic? Or it's analytic except at $z=0$, but it's uncomfortable for me because the term "except $z=0$", I mean, is one single point affect the whole analyticity and we have to redefine our function to exclude that point?

Actually I've seen my possibility duplicate,  not really clear to me.

Please use easy explanatory to me, cz I'm new in this course.

Thanks.

Comment: So, every function that has singularity at certain point, then it can't be analytic?

Comment: A function could be analytic without being an entire function. An entire function is, by definition, analytic at every (in a neighborhood of every) finite point of the complex plane. The function $\frac1z$ is not entire, but nevertheless it is analytic on the punctured finite complex plane (excluding $\infty$ and the origin).

Comment: $1/z$ is analytic around $z_0 \ne 0$ because of the geometric series $$1/z = 1/z_0 \sum_{k\ge 0} (-(z-z_0)/z_0)^k, |z-z_0|<|z_0|$$ It is complex differentiable thus holomorphic for quite the same reason $$\frac1{f(z_0)+(z-z_0)f'(z_0)+o(z-z_0)} = \frac1{f(z_0)}(1-(z-z_0)f'(z_0)/f(z_0)+o(z-z_0))$$. It is a theorem (Cauchy's integral formula) that holomorphic implies analytic.